# How can the F-35 be used in Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Apart from the obvious “giving the SU-35s a bunch of kills”, how can the F-35s be used effectively?

They turn too slowly to reliably engage the SU-35s, and when they are hovering they aren't maneuverable enough to engage land units (engineers or armoured).

Answer (score 3):

The F-35, especially when equipped with Rocket Pods or Guided Missiles, makes an excellent mid-to-long range standoff weapons platform.  Hover up from behind some obstruction or building, fire a volley at enemy ground forces, then hover back down.  It is extremely vulnerable to anti-air assets, so proper utilization of ground cover and range (to outrun incoming missiles) is extremely important.